# upgrading sql server 2008 R2 express edition to standard edition

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2008-express

I am using sql server 2008 R2 express edition,it only supports 10 Gb DB space.
how can i get know how much space is used and how much free space i have balance,i have tried sp_spaceused, but i didn't get clear answer.
i think i have 2 DB's.
and if i want to upgrade 2008 R2 express edition to 2008 R2 standard edition what is the procedure?, can i upgrade directly or need to take backup and uninstall express edition and then need to install standard edition?.
is that anything i need to pay (for license) to upgrade to standard edition?

Comment: Standard isn't free but google will tell you this.

Comment: This question belongs either in the superuser.com Stack Exchange forum or in the Microsoft SQL Server Setup and Upgrade forum:  https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/home?forum=sqlsetupandupgrade

Comment: @THeron:DBA.SE suits best

Answer (score 0):

Standard edition will require you to pay a fee fro licensing. As far as upgrading you can just install standard edition without uninstalling express. I would then take a backup for you express database and restore it to the standard edition then uninstall express once everything is working. As far as the space used Right click on your DB name in SSMS and select properties and that will tell you how much space that particular DB is using.

Comment: the first DB shows size 6624.19 MB and space available 37.97 MB, and the second DB shows size 1116.00 MB and space available 7.90 MB it means i have only 45.87 mb remaining balance?

Comment: Actually it is 10 GB per DB. For example you can have 10 database all at 9GB and not exceed the size limits.